# Junit order of execution of test methods

Tags: java, junit

I want to know which of the following test methods runs first?
    @BeforeClass
    @AfterClass
    @Before
    @After
    @test

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a test with each of these methods, print something inside, execute the test, and see by yourself. Or read the documentation (gasp!): http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/

Comment: Aside from reading the documentation: how is this not the most obvious sequence ever?

Comment: I'm new to Junit test :) and I don't know what should I do if I want to test a method. Should I do all the five tests or just one.

Comment: `@Test` is how you mark your test methods.  The others are used for setup, teardown, etc to support your tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have one test:

- @BeforeClass
- @Before
- @Test
- @After
- @AfterClass

If you have two tests:

- @BeforeClass
- @Before
- @Test
- @After
- @Before
- @Test
- @After
- @AfterClass

etc.

Comment: What if I have a constructor in the test class?

Comment: The constructor runs before @Before in the flow of my post.